# How to manipulate a Dataframe which contains multiple lines of signals and plot signal vs. time using parallel_coordinates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I work with a quite large table (50MB) which has a similar format to the following table:

[image]

I would like to manipulate the dataframe using pandas' `stack`, `unstack`, `set_index`, `pivot`, `pivot_table` function or in any other idiomatic fashion, so I'll be able to plot all `size` signals as function of time. For example, plotting the `size` column at the different time points using `parallel_coordinates`.

```
iteration   weight  count edge  blobs   days    frame   start   time    size
1   7   600 100 1000    0   0   0   0
1   7   600 100 1000    1   2   2   13.5
2   3   600 100 333 0   0   0   19.5
2   3   600 100 333 1   2   2   25.5
3   4   600 100 1000    0   0   0   22.5
3   4   600 100 1000    1   2   2   24
```

Then once I plot the individual signal as function of time, I want to average over the different iterations of the same physical condition (where `weight, count, edge, blobs, days time` are the same).

**EDIT:**

I think that if I find an easy way to convert the original dataframe to this one, we will be able to plot all the `size` vs. `time` signals:

[image]

Or maybe something like that:

[image]

Comment: What is expected output from your sample data?

Comment: @jezrael, any layout that will allow me to plot all the signals (`average length` vs. `time`) on the same plot in bokeh or matplotlib.

Comment: @jezrael, I added a possible output of the dataframe which will allow us to plot the signals vs. time